# Applying Constraints Programmatically to UITableViewCell and SubViews

Tags: ios

I am trying to learn how to apply constraints to build a UITableViewCell. I am using iOS 10 using Swift. Here is my requirement.

[image]

I want to apply constraints to the green control which is a button and make sure that it is on the right hand side as shown above.

```
countView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        countView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
```

I have supplied the width and height constraints as above. But I don't know how to put it on the right hand side of the cell with some space as a margin.

UPDATE: I don't see anything on the screen.

countView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

```
self.addSubview(countView)

countView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
countView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
countView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
countView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Look up `.trailingAnchor` to position it to the right-hand side, and `.centerYAnchor` for, as you might guess, centering it on the Y axis.

Comment: Updated the code I still don't see anything.

Comment: First, are you setting `countView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`? Second, you will want your `.trailingAnchor` to be a negative value... i.e. the right-edge of the green box should be -20 pts from the right-edge of the blue box.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! I got it with your help :)